# Python function to find and tokenize string data

Tags: python, regex

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import nltk.corpus

def tokenize(text, **kw):
    """
    Break down text into a set of unique lower case words.
    """
    plain_words = nltk.corpus.abc.words()
    stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()
    # Defaults
    kw.setdefault('min_len', 4)
    kw.setdefault('max_len', 0)
    kw.setdefault('ignore_list', [])
    kw['ignore_list'] += stop_words

    ok_length = lambda token: [len(token) >= kw['min_len']
                             and kw['max_len'] <= kw['max_len']][0]

    tokens = set([token.lower()
                  for token in re.findall('([A-z]+)+', text)
                  if ok_length(token) and
                  token not in kw['ignore_list']]).intersection(plain_words)

    return tokens

## TESTING tokenize

TEXT = open('/bin/bash', 'r').read()

print tokenize(TEXT,
               min_len=4,
               max_len=0,
               ignore_list=['code'])
```

My concerns:

1. Is `tokenize()` too complex as one function?
2. Should I replace the list comprehensions?
3. Does this regex `'([A-z]+)+'` need improving?
4. How could I make this code more idiomatic?
5. Have I overlooked any faults in any of the logic?

Example output:

```
11:26 PM$ python Tokenize.py 
set(['replacing', 'default', 'all', 'forget', 'chain', 'skip', 'global', 'dollar', 'splitting', 'existing', 'four', 'executing', 'go', 'follow', 'expressions', 'activates', 'saved', 'children', 'causes', 'row', 'whose', 'tv', 'graph', 'discard', 'send', 'environment', 'to', 'topic', 'program', 'marks', 'include', 'sent', 'allocate', 'division', 'random', 'slash', 'dynamic', 'reserved', 'removing', 'manipulated', 'every', 'nesting', 'decide', 'entries', 'locked', 'syntax', 'exact', 'condition', 'entire', 'redistribute', 'magic', 'exits', 'level', 'turns', 'array', 'exec', 'list', 'fewer', 'try', 'mm', 'quick', 'refer', 'upper', 'unexpected', 'force', 'portable', 'be', 'obsolete', 'sign', 'jump', 'consists', 'second', 'displays', 'insertion', 'pass', 'gm', 'even', 'index', 'errors', 'adds', 'sub', 'directive', 'near', 'supplied', 'current', 'seconds', 'waiting', 'version', 'new', 'movement', 'redirect', 'full', 'simultaneously', 'exchange', 'respectively', 'error', 'commercial', 'equals', 'reported', 'objects', 'let', 'undo', 'groups', 'erm', 'active', 'path', '[', 'diagnostic', 'appears', 'change', 'wait', 'digits', 'great', 'copyright', 'coerced', 'handlers', 'items', 'changed', 'allows', 'reports', 'ignoring', 'amount', 'resulting', 'menu', 'usually', 'history', 'makes', 'exited', 'missing', 'composed', 'named', 'via', 'useful', 'extra', 'prefer', 'logical', 'replace', 'visible', 'names', 'apply', 'unit', 'use', 'takes', 'working', 'nine', 'escapes', 'two', 'next', 'r', 'duplicate', 'handler', 'call', 'memory', 'scope', 'type', 'until', 'more', 'separated', 'successful', 'initial', 'operators', 'tested', 'flag', 'controlling', 'encountered', 'disabling', 'must', 'me', 'escaped', 'none', 'te', 'word', 'err', 'indicates', 'this', 'loops', 'work', 'mi', 'modified', 'abort', 'values', 'can', 'socket', 'following', 'making', 'closing', 'my', 'example', 'performed', 'control', 'del', 'prompt', 'links', 'give', 'process', 'lock', 'functions', 'share', 'accept', 'trap', 'high', 'effectively', 'tag', 'numbers', 'allowed', 'scheduling', 'counting', 'audible', 'information', 'rather', 'means', 'j', 'write', 'how', 'silent', 'instead', 'profile', 'map', 'fr', 'blocks', 'description', 'may', 'max', 'resumes', 'tries', 'disable', 'coming', 'date', 'horizontal', 'law', 'data', 'types', 'fo', 'a', 'ambiguous', 'short', 'physical', 'remember', 'third', 'whenever', 'maybe', 'lines', 'bugs', 'element', 'provide', 'expression', 'allow', 'decreasing', 'scroll', 'subsequently', 'operate', 'order', 'se', 'feed', 'breaking', 'interpretation', 'help', 'disables', 'move', 'displayed', 'interpreted', 'disabled', 'timing', 'suspend', 'un', 'differs', 'interpreter', 'still', 'pointer', 'positional', 'style', 'le', 'group', 'monitor', 'curly', 'shifts', 'lo', 'll', 'detected', 'lu', 'systems', 'listing', 'mail', 'hidden', 'main', 'pending', 'split', 'non', 'return', 'greater', 'output', 'matches', 'auto', 'runs', 'number', 'break', 'internally', 'blink', 'killed', 'matched', 'term', 'name', 'ifs', 'always', 'revert', 'identified', 'privileged', 'possibilities', 'applied', 'token', 'inequality', 'stopped', 'mode', 'arrow', 'each', 'found', 'cc', 'reset', 'preceded', 'square', 'invoked', 'generation', 'ed', 'chunk', 'hard', 'frames', 'expect', 'exceeded', 'eu', 'et', 'operation', 'bay', 'event', 'special', 'intended', 'large', 'shown', 'network', 'space', 'restricted', 'since', 'preserve', 'unknown', 'looking', 're', 'acting', 'flushing', 'exporting', 'print', 'got', 'rn', 'cause', 'occurs', 'common', 'foundation', 'turning', 'resume', 'free', 'standard', 'indices', 'base', 'execute', 'put', 'org', 'wanted', 'beginning', 'l', 'software', 'resumed', 'definition', 'g', 'created', 'locations', 'retrieving', 'messages', 'times', 'creates', 'turn', 'length', 'place', 'w', 'assumed', 'timed', 'onto', 'assign', 'first', 'origin', 'already', 'succeeds', 'omitted', 'variables', 'symbolic', 'primary', 'owned', 'one', 'restrict', 'hook', 'done', 'notify', 'suspended', 'blank', 'reached', 'message', 'open', 'braces', 'size', 'given', 'checked', 'exists', 'service', 'redirection', 'meaningful', 'top', 'behaves', 'accent', 'system', 'construct', 'priority', 'indicate', 'returns', 'listed', 'passed', 'typing', 'white', 'final', 'gives', 'shell', 'option', 'trapped', 'ch', 'completed', 'exactly', 'lists', 'copy', 'completes', 'specify', 'character', 'begins', 'b', 'target', 'quantum', 'instruction', 'enabled', 'depends', 'i', 'determined', 'bind', 'enables', 'declare', 'interactive', 'and', 'files', 'false', 'topics', 'turned', 'argument', 'dash', 'width', 'need', 'seen', 'any', 'contents', 'forced', 'zero', 'depending', 'self', 'note', 'also', 'internal', 'build', 'indexed', 'destroy', 'copied', 'brace', 'begin', 'added', 'unless', 'trace', 'normal', 'buffer', 'object', 'leave', 'regular', 'eight', 'printed', 'letter', 'termination', 'nothing', 'alpha', 'segment', 'associative', 'grave', 'appear', 'kg', 'foreground', 'clear', 'later', 'm', 'km', 'looked', 'bracket', 'keywords', 'pattern', 'normally', 'notion', 'selection', 'show', 'text', 'supported', 'brief', 'session', 'beg', 'conditional', 'find', 'completion', 'access', 'based', 'quoted', 'parameters', 'implementation', 'true', 'specified', 'assertion', 'controls', 'terminal', 'failed', 'only', 'inherited', 'override', 'query', 'local', 'columns', 'do', 'specifications', 'invoke', 'get', 'convert', 'de', 'stop', 'da', 'cannot', 'negative', 'words', 'reply', 'report', 'du', 'procedures', 'sorts', 'secondary', 'processes', 'resource', 'horizontally', 'fields', 'remove', 'calling', 'arrays', 'bad', 'processed', 'contain', 'release', 'x', 'fixed', 'automatic', 'flagged', 'ignored', 'set', 'dump', 'frame', 'prints', 'maximum', 'relative', 'see', 'result', 'successive', 'sequences', 'fails', 'evaluation', 'vertical', 'placed', 'ways', 'subsequent', 'currently', 'written', 'protected', 'neither', 'reading', 'conditions', 'checks', 'available', 'suppresses', 'jobs', 'parent', 'opening', 'modify', 'screen', 'sole', 'transpose', 'disallow', 'nd', 'job', 'succeed', 'selectively', 'key', 'interface', 'printing', 'optional', 'valid', 'hits', 'last', 'reverse', 'limits', 'many', 'region', 'la', 'according', 'minus', 'etc', 's', 'context', 'attributes', 'delete', 'whole', 'botched', 'otherwise', 'load', 'pre', 'permitted', 'co', 'extent', 'point', 'simple', 'effective', 'period', 'pop', 'cz', 'simply', 'unsuccessful', 'table', 'allocated', 'indefinite', 'suppressing', 'described', 'duo', 'addition', 'shells', 'create', 'three', 'mark', 'pc', 'treat', 'expected', 'entered', 'empty', 'define', 'generating', 'enable', 'corresponding', 'suppress', 'sufficient', 'search', 'else', 'child', 'an', 'assigning', 'present', '^', 'case', 'handling', 'license', 'these', 'plain', 'expanded', 'examine', 'value', 'n', 'while', 'replaced', 'behavior', 'shift', 'evaluates', 'di', 'property', 'precede', 'loop', 'seven', 've', 'resident', 'is', 'dumped', 'binding', 'it', 'equal', 'vu', 'in', 'ie', 'if', 'binary', 'containing', 'perform', 'make', 'attribute', 'member', 'read', 'arguments', 'freed', 'modification', 'document', 'events', 'resources', 'status', 'used', 'temporary', 'receives', 'keys', 'reporting', 'upon', 'effect', 'alert', 'action', 'running', 'levels', 'uses', 'user', 'characters', 'stack', 'expand', 'recent', 'lower', 'older', 'shared', 'changes', 'well', 'spent', 'options', 'patterns', 'without', 'flags', 'sets', 'y', 'position', 'the', 'left', 'comment', 'newest', 'sourced', 'less', 'percent', 'obtain', 'actions', 'assigned', 'stored', 'kill', 'immediately', 'followed', 'alternative', 'rotates', 'previous', 'adding', 'loading', 'generator', 'grouped', 'bell', 'guaranteed', 'except', 'signals', 'source', 'add', 'setting', 'combine', 'location', 'usage', 'input', 'reusable', 'interprets', 'remaining', 'match', 'take', 'real', 'tests', 'format', 'rules', 'evaluate', 'showing', 'unlimited', 'possible', 'five', 'background', 'using', 'bit', 'accepted', 'string', 'd', 'insert', 'appearing', 'like', 'success', 'sizes', 'signal', 'performing', 'manual', 'specific', 'exhausted', 'continue', 'hosts', 't', 'become', 'soft', 'attempting', 'right', 'old', 'often', 'sequence', 'oriented', 'creation', 'some', 'back', 'oh', 'export', 'evaluated', 'loaded', 'duration', 'multiple', 'matching', 'reasons', 'ignore', 'describing', 'for', 'notification', 'avoid', 'though', 'comments', 'disk', 'exit', 'select', 'provides', 'indication', 'leader', 'either', 'core', 'command', 'run', 'remembered', 'equivalent', 'processing', 'continuing', 'bi', 'expansion', 'utilities', 'host', 'display', 'offset', 'leftover', 'post', 'refers', 'by', 'comparison', 'pipeline', 'ok', 'would', 'getting', 'column', 'of', 'http', 'o', 'page', 'stamp', 'range', 'plus', 'stand', 'illegal', 'connected', 'os', 'or', 'block', 'op', 'contains', 'letters', 'previously', 'within', 'bound', 'son', 'en', 'determine', 'operator', 'accumulated', 'exchanges', 'terminated', 'statistics', 'additional', 'waits', ']', 'there', 'question', 'long', 'start', 'restricts', 'editor', 'way', 'forward', 'eg', 'combined', 'function', 'head', 'successfully', 'complete', 'form', 'hr', 'attempted', 'removes', 'commands', 'failure', 'manipulate', 'hi', 'link', 'newer', 'line', 'with', 'bug', 'he', 'count', 'entry', 'places', 'versions', 'whether', 'wish', 'caller', 'up', 'us', 'record', 'carriage', 'converted', 'limit', 'fetch', 'pm', 'similar', 'called', 'connect', 'detailed', 'storing', 'definitions', 'associated', 'ad', 'ag', 'defined', 'pseudo', 'universal', 'escape', 'incremental', 'al', 'general', 'consumed', 'single', 'warning', 'exist', 'at', 'file', 'home', 'importing', 'trailing', 'check', 'defines', 'echo', 'pipe', 'marking', 'remainder', 'no', 'when', 'virtual', 'started', 'other', 'outputs', 'test', 'you', 'acceptable', 'arithmetic', 'formats', 'elements', 'star', 'colon', 'separate', 'preceding', 'searched', 'reused', 'includes', 'generated', 'exported', 'variable', 'structure', 'opened', 'e', 'requires', 'required', 'mask', 'visual', 'strings', 'u', 'time', 'directory', 'backward', 'starting', 'original'])
```

Answer (score 5):

1. No, `tokenize` is not too complex for one function. It does a single operation: it tokenizes a string.
2. Your list comprehensions are fine. They are somewhat complex but are still readable and easily understandable.
3. Instead of using the regex `([A-z]+)+` you could simply use the 'shortcut' `\w+'. This regex will match one-to-many words.

   If you wanted your regex to recognize hyphenated words, a simple change will suffice:

   ```
   \w(-?\w)*
   ```
4. Your code is quite Pythonic. Your spacing and indentation is fine. The same goes for your variable names. If you have more concerns about style, consult [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide.
5. There is a flaw in your logic though. Take your `lambda` expression:

   ```
   ok_length = lambda token: [len(token) >= kw['min_len']
                        and kw['max_len'] <= kw['max_len']][0]
   ```

   Currently, this will except any string whose length is **greater** than the `min_length` this is because you have `kw['max_len'] == kw['max_len']` which will always evaluate `True`. You also have the conditionals switched around. This is how you should have the check:

   ```
   ok_length = lambda token: [kw['min_length'] <= len(token) <= kw['max_length']][0]
   ```

   Now, the question you need to ask is, whether or not it pays off to use a `lambda` expression here. Is the functionality 'deserving' of a `lambda` expression? Or can the check simply be placed into the list comprehension a little later on? Here's what it would look like, I'll let you decide (I like this way):

   ```
   tokens = set([token.lower()
             for token in re.findall('([A-z]+)+', text)
             if kw['min_len'] <= len(token) <= kw['max_len'] and
             token not in kw['ignore_list']]).intersection(plain_words)
   ```
6. The next thing I would consider is your used of the `kw` dict. How needed is it? Could you just implement optional parameters in the function declaration? I like that implementation because this function does not (and probably won't) take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments. It will only take the 3. As a related side note, you have swapped your `max_len` and `min_len` values. Currently, `max_len < min_len`.
7. Finally, I would remove the `intersection` function call when you assign the `tokens` variable. The name `tokens` and the context with which its generated implies that `tokens` will hold all tokens that match the given regex. However, in your case, it only contains that are also in `plain_words`. I would wait to do the intersection until the `return` statement:

   ```
   return tokens.intersection(plain_words)
   ```

Here is 'my' version of the `tokenize` function:

```
def tokenize(text, min_len=0, max_len=4, ignore_list=[]):
    """
    Break down text into a set of unique lower case words.
    """
    plain_words = nltk.corpus.abc.words()
    stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()
    ignore_list += stop_words

    tokens = set([token.lower()
                  for token in re.findall('\w+', text)
                  if min_len <= len(token) <= max_len and
                  token not in kw['ignore_list']])

    return tokens.intersection(plain_words)
```